# tsql - Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need help with this Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I'm trying to run a simple query on an @as_of_date, 10 days ago and 30 days ago.  The query works fine if I run it on 3-5 accounts, but any more than that if fails.  How do I change my query so that I don't get the conversion error?

Here's my sample query:
[image]

**Edit**

Also tried removing the quotes from the select statement.  Still doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: you are attempting to convert a string `"@as_of_date"` instead of value of variable with that name. remove quotes.

Comment: Why on earth are you typing `mm-dd-yyyy` instead of a format that can't be misinterpreted by regional/language settings, like `yyyymmdd`? Please [read this in full](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx). Also, show all of the code, as I don't believe the error is happening in the portion you've shown.

Comment: I think my issue is much larger.  My query will run fine for the first 1370 records, but when I change the query to the top 1371 it throws the "conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string" message.  I'm also not able to order by any column. I think it's a problem with the table and have sent a message to the developer.

Comment: @Showstopper as @Aaron said you've to change this line `CONVERT(date,'02-25-2015',110)` to `CONVERT(date,'2015-2-25',110)`. This one is correct format.

Comment: 1) `@as_of_date` actually is of type `date` so no conversion needed 2) you are hiding problematic part of query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using ISDATE function to see the input data is a valid date.. Also I don't see in the screenshot how/what is the input.

Comment: The ISDATE function fixed the issue.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are converting the `@as_of_date` twice. 
You can use `SELECT convert(date, getdate(), 110)`
Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't working.  I removed the convert and just used 'currentday' = @as_of_date and i still get the conversation failed error message.

Answer (score 0):

please remove quotes for @asofdate  variable in select statement and try like  convert(date,@as_of_date,110)

Note:While assigning the value to the variable only its converting ,so no need to convert once again in select statement

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work.  See my edited version above.